# How to get transaction PDF in NetSuite

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0, suitetalk

I'm able to get transaction internal id by suitetalk api, but it doesn't have API to get transaction in PDF format.

Would anyone help me in this case?

Comment: Not sure about Suitetalik, but you can use SuiteScript to get the PDF versions of records.  Worst case you could build a RESTlet to return it...?  Not sure if that helps, though.

Comment: Hi @W3BGUY, thank you for your comment. Do you have an example of that for RESTlet?

Comment: I'll add some code to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of the email.send to attach a file.  I don't currently have a NetSuite account to log into, but the 2.0 code below is an example of the email.send module that you can use to email the record(s).  If you search that in the NS docs, you'll find more examples, as well.

```
email.send({
  author:emailAudthorNSID, 
  recipients:emailRecipientNSID, 
  subject:'Example email subject', 
  body:'Example Email Body', 
  relatedRecords:{
    transactionId:transactionRecordToAttach
  }
});
```

Comment: I think that's just going to add the email to the Communication tab of the transaction, not actually attach the PDF of the transaction to the email, right?